# Cross fade background-image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

so I have some images and I would like to show them as a slideshow in the background. However, I want the image to cross-fade between the current image and the next image. So far, I have only been able to switch between the images:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var images = ["landing_background_1.jpg", "landing_background_2.jpg", "landing_background_3.jpg", "landing_background_4.jpg"];

    var currentImage = 0;


    function changeBackgroundImage() {


        $("html").fadeIn().css({

            "background-image": "url('img/backgrounds/" + images[++currentImage] + "')",

        });


        if (currentImage >= images.length - 1) {

            //set it back to the begining
            currentImage -= images.length;

        }

    }


    setInterval(changeBackgroundImage, 1500);

});
```

Any help would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: A cross fade done in JS will require two separately visible images with one fading out, the other fading in.  You can't just switch a single image with plain javascript like you are trying to do and get a cross fade.  You can apparently do that with CSS3.

Comment: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have to do is layer two element on top of each other.  Then have one fadeout and the other fadein.

Here is how I would go about doing it ...

css ...

```
#background-images {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 1;
    }

#bImg1 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 3; 
    background: url(starting-img1.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
    }

#bImg2 {
    display: none;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 2; 
    background: url(starting-img2.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: contain;
    }

.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: 900px;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

The html ...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="background-images">
        <div id="bImg1"></div>
        <div id="bImg2"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        Content Here
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The script ...

```
var imageSet1 = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg"];
var currentImageSet1 = 0;

var imageSet2 = ["image4.jpg", "image5.jpg", "image6.jpg"];
var currentImageSet2 = 0;

function changeBackgroundImages() {
    img1Fade();
    setTimeout(img2Fade, 2000);

}

function img1Fade(){

    $('#bImg1').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#bImg1').css({background: 'url(' + imageSet1[++currentImageSet1] + ')'})});
    $('#bImg2').fadeIn('slow');
    if (currentImageSet1 >= imageSet1.length - 1) {

            currentImageSet1 -= imageSet1.length;
        };
}

function img2Fade(){

    $('#bImg2').fadeOut('slow', function(){$('#bImg2').css({background: 'url(' + imageSet2[++currentImageSet2] + ')'})});
    $('#bImg1').fadeIn('slow');
    if (currentImageSet2 >= imageSet2.length - 1) {

            currentImageSet2 -= imageSet2.length;
        };
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(changeBackgroundImages, 5000);
});
```

You will need to mess with the timing to get it to look good.  Make sure to set your urls to the images in the image array or when the sting in the css is built.

Comment: Yes, but I don't understand how I can target a background image like that using jquery.

Answer (score 5):

I've spent a lot of time to find the most clean and easy way.
This finally works:

```js
var i=0;
var imghead=[
 "url(http://yoururl.com/picture0.jpg)",
 "url(http://yoururl.com/picture1.jpg)"
 ];//add as many images as you like

function slideimg() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        jQuery('#element').css('background-image', imghead[i]);
        i++;
        if(i==imghead.length) i=0;
        slideimg();
    }, 6000);
}
slideimg();
```

```css
#element{
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 opacity: 1.0;
 -webkit-transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
 -moz-transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
 -o-transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
 -ms-transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
 transition: background-image 1.5s linear;
}
```

Comment: This works in Webkit based browsers but is not standard; `background-image` is not an animatable property: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transitions-1/#animatable-properties

Answer (score 0):

Easier:

```
var current = 1;
function anim() {
   if(current == 4) {current = 1;   }
   $('#bImg'+ current).fadeOut(3000);
   ++current;
   $('#bImg'+ current).fadeIn(3000);
   setTimeout(anim, 8000);
}
anim();
```

html:

```
 <div class="inside" >
        <div id="bImg2"></div>    
        <div id="bImg3"></div>    
    </div>
```

css:

```
.inside {
 background:url(top_01.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
}


#bImg2 {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background:url(top_02.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
 display: none;
}

  #bImg3 { 
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
background:url(top_03.jpg) no-repeat center top ;
 display: none;
}
```