# Where to add fadein function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

i am trying to add FadeIn in hover changing background script and in any way it isn't working. Basically I am trying to make background change in some elegant way, not a instantly blinking. Maybe there is better way to animate this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QLw3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOB2.png)
EDIT:

I have made fullscreen menu, where you have on left half of screen 2 photos (#menu-photo-small/.menu-photo) that change when you hover over menu (#changeX). Thing is, that script is working but I am trying to animate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#change1").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change1.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change1.jpg)");
  }, function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
  });
  
  $("#change2").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change2.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change2.jpg)");
  }, function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
  });
  
  $("#change3").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change3.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change3.jpg)");
  }, function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
  });
  
  $("#change4").hover(function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change4.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/menuhover/change4.jpg)");
  }, function() {
    $("#menu-photo-small").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
    $(".menu-photo").css("background-image", "url(./photos/background.jpg)");
  });
});
```

Comment: What kind of effect are you looking for? one image to fade out and another to fade in simultaneously (cross-fade?)

Comment: Lots of suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=animate+background+image+opacity)

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML to the question so we can more effectively understand the context of the JS, and also DRY it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't entirely clear, but if its a cross-fade to another background image, you are looking for, you are probably better of using CSS3 transitions instead of animating with jQuery.

check out:
[Cross fade background-image with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18346577/cross-fade-background-image-with-jquery)

EDIT: To answer your question as stated in the question title, adding a fadeIn() won't work with the code provided.

Comment: Thanks, I edited question to provide more accurate description of problem. Because I do not want continous animation